# Make list of partially applied functions (elegantly or idiomatically)

Tags: haskell, currying

I can mostly stumble my way through my Haskell questions, but I haven't found a better solution to my problem.

Suppose that I have a function `f` that takes 5 parameters and I want to create a list of partially-applied functions that have the first 3 parameters applied, but different in every element of the list.

For example, let's say that `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> b -> b -> c` and I want to end up with `[b -> b -> c]` as the type of the result. One of the functions might be `f 1 3 5` and another might be `f 6 4 2`.

With 1 argument I could just do something like

```
map f [1..4]
```

to get `f 1`, `f 2`, etc., and with 2 args I could do

```
map (uncurry f) $ zip [1..3] [6..8].
```

Now for 3 args I could do

```
map (uncurry $ uncurry f) $ zip (zip [1..3] [6..8]) [3..5]
```

but this is getting awfully ugly awfully fast. Is there a more elegant (or idiomatic) way to do this (aside from making my own "uncurry3" function to pair with `zip3`)? I've always run into an elegant solution with Haskell, and this seems very clumsy.

Sorry if this is a newbie question or has been answered before. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can shorten your 2-argument code with `zipWith`:

```
zipWith f [1..3] [6..8]
```

And conveniently, there are is actually a [`zipWith3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zipWith3) (and so on up to 7) defined in the standard library.

There are also [parallel list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Parallel_list_comprehension) with `-XParallelListComp` which seem to go up to any number:

```
[f a b c | a <- [1..3] | b <- [6..8] | c <- [3..5]]
```

Comment: zipWith<N> should do just fine for me, I don't have an obscene number of args, but thanks for the heads up on parallel list comps.

Answer (score 9):

This is actually one way to define an Applicative instance for Lists.

Recall that Applicative's definition revolves around the definition of `(<*>)`:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And if you specialize for `[]`, you can get:

```
(<*>) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
```

Maybe this is starting to look like a way you can make this happen?  You have a list of functions, and you can apply them to a list of values.  Perhaps we can make `(<*>)` work in a way so that it applies the list of functions to the list of values like a zip:

```
fs <*> xs = zipWith ($) fs xs
```

Recall `($)`, the function application operator:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

So `zipWith` "zips" a list of functions and a list of values and returns the result of applying each function to the corresponding value.

I think you should probably be able to take it from here.  Let's add together two lists:

```
(fmap (+) [1,2,3]) <*> [4,5,6]
```

which turns into

```
[(1+), (2+), (3+)] <*> [4,5,6]
```

which turns into

```
[1+4, 2+5, 3+6]
```

and

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

How about a three argument function?

```
f x y z = x * y + z

((fmap f [1,2,3]) <*> [4,5,6]) <*> [7,8,9]
([(\y z -> 1*y+z), (\y z > 2*y+z), (\y z -> 3*y+z)] <*> [4,5,6]) <*> [7,8,9]
[(4+), (10+), (18+)] <*> [7,8,9]
[11, 18, 27]
```

Neat!

It isn't too hard to see that you can extend this to arbitrary-arity functions by just taking on another `(<*>)`.

Also, we can define a convenient alias for `fmap` with the right fixity and call it `(<$>)`, and also define `(<*>)` to have the correct fixity to not need parentheses, and we can do something like

```
f <$> [1,2,3] <*> [4,5,6] <*> [7,8,9]
```

Which is neat, right?  Now you can basically do a `zipWithN`...`zipWith` with as many arguments as you want!

Unfortunately the default Applicative instance for `[]` doesn't have this behavior; it behaves in a way consistent with its Monad instance.  So to get around this, we usually use a newtype wrapper to let us define different instances for the same type.  In the standard libraries, in `Control.Applicative`, the newtype wrapper is `ZipList`:

```
data ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }

instance Applicative ZipList where
    (ZipList fs) <*> (ZipList xs) = ZipList (zipWith ($) fs xs)
    pure x                        = -- left as exercise, it might surprise you :)
```

So we can do the above in real Haskell as:

```
f <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5,6] <*> ZipList [7,8,9]
```

Which is slightly more verbose than the original version, unfortunately --- and a bit more verbose than

```
zipWith3 f [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]
```

But the "advantage" is that you can do basically arbitrary fixity "lifting" :)

The real thing to take away here is that this is "exactly the kind of pattern" that Applicative was invented to solve; it's a very common pattern/domain that Applicative particularly *thrives* in, and it might be nice to begin building an intuition to be able to spot the tell-tale signs of a problem that might be a good fit for an Applicative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial!

Comment: I recall from way back some discussion that this version of `(<*>)` for lists should be included as a function in the basic libraries, but alas that hasn't happened.  However it exists as `zap` in Edward Kmett's `keys` package.